# Function minimization using minimize from scipy

Tags: python, optimization, minimization

I would like to minimize the following cost function

[image]

where h_u and h_v are the vectors of real numbers.
I am doing this in Python, but I am not sure that the function `minimize` from `scipy.optimize` package is what I need.

My approach is the following:
given `h_u` and `h_v` as two matrices with dimensionality

```
print(h_u.shape, h_v.shape)
>>>(12458, 7) (12458, 7)
```

I define objective function

```
fun = lambda h: (h[0]*h[1]).mean()
```

Then I stack the vectors

```
h_in = np.stack((h_u, h_v), axis = 0)
```

and try to minimize

```
minimized = minimize(fun, x0 = h_in)
```

I am not sure that providing `h_in` as an initial guess `x0` is correct, because it produces an error

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 227. GiB for an array with shape (174412, 174412) and data type float64
```

Could somebody tell me if I do it correctly and how could I circumvent the error?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using scipy.optimize.minimize is not suitable for your problem, as it's meant for continuous problems (most of its methods use a gradient).

I did not compute the memory usage, but in general I'd propose something like this; if the memory is not large enough to fit the whole list comprehension, you can break it down to one loop inside the comprehension and loop over the other vectors, cache the results and compare them to the newly found minimum for that vector.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((5,2)).T
a[0,:] *= 2

b = np.arange(10).reshape((5,2)).T

min_index_flat = np.argmin([sum(i*j) for i in a for j in b])

min_index_a = min_index_flat // len(a)
min_index_b = min_index_flat % len(b)
```

EDIT: That is under the assumption that you want to find the minimum of all possible combinations; I just realized that that depends on your set `epsilon`, but if you just want to compare pairwise, the code would just get easier: `min_index_flat = np.argmin([sum(i*j) for i,j in zip(a,b)])`